# Drawing decision boundaries in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, nearest-neighbor

I've got a series of modelled class labels from the `knn` function. I've got a data frame with basic numeric training data, and another data frame for test data. How would I go about drawing a decision boundary for the returned values from the `knn` function? I'll have to replicate my findings on a locked-down machine, so please limit the use of 3rd party libraries if possible.

I only have two class labels, "orange" and "blue". They're plotted on a simple 2D plot with the training data. Again, I just want to draw a boundary around the results from the `knn` function.

Code:

```
library(class)

n <- 100

set.seed(1)
x <- round(runif(n, 1, n))
set.seed(2)
y <- round(runif(n, 1, n))
train.df <- data.frame(x, y)

set.seed(1)
x.test <- round(runif(n, 1, n))
set.seed(2)
y.test <- round(runif(n, 1, n))
test.df <- data.frame(x.test, y.test)

k <- knn(train.df, test.df, classes, k=25)

plot(test.df, col=k)
```

`classes` is just a vector of class labels determined from an earlier bit of code.

If you need it, below is the complete code for my work:

```
library(class)

n <- 100
set.seed(1)
x <- round(runif(n, 1, n))
set.seed(2)
y <- round(runif(n, 1, n))

# ============================================================
# Bayes Classifier + Decision Boundary Code
# ============================================================

classes <- "null"
colours <- "null"

for (i in 1:n)
{

    # P(C = j | X = x, Y = y) = prob
    # "The probability that the class (C) is orange (j) when X is some x, and Y is some y"
    # Two predictors that influence classification: x, y
    # If x and y are both under 50, there is a 90% chance of being orange (grouping)
    # If x and y and both over 50, or if one of them is over 50, grouping is blue
    # Algorithm favours whichever grouping has a higher chance of success, then plots using that colour
    # When prob (from above) is 50%, the boundary is drawn

    percentChance <- 0
    if (x[i] < 50 && y[i] < 50)
    {
        # 95% chance of orange and 5% chance of blue
        # Bayes Decision Boundary therefore assigns to orange when x < 50 and y < 50
        # "colours" is the Decision Boundary grouping, not the plotted grouping
        percentChance <- 95
        colours[i] <- "orange"
    }
    else
    {
        percentChance <- 10
        colours[i] <- "blue"
    }

    if (round(runif(1, 1, 100)) > percentChance)
    {
        classes[i] <- "blue"
    }
    else
    {
        classes[i] <- "orange"
    }
}

boundary.x <- seq(0, 100, by=1)
boundary.y <- 0
for (i in 1:101)
{
    if (i > 49)
    {
        boundary.y[i] <- -10 # just for the sake of visual consistency, real value is 0
    }
    else
    {
        boundary.y[i] <- 50
    }
}
df <- data.frame(boundary.x, boundary.y)

plot(x, y, col=classes)
lines(df, type="l", lty=2, lwd=2, col="red")

# ============================================================
# K-Nearest neighbour code
# ============================================================

#library(class)

#n <- 100

#set.seed(1)
#x <- round(runif(n, 1, n))
#set.seed(2)
#y <- round(runif(n, 1, n))
train.df <- data.frame(x, y)

set.seed(1)
x.test <- round(runif(n, 1, n))
set.seed(2)
y.test <- round(runif(n, 1, n))
test.df <- data.frame(x.test, y.test)

k <- knn(train.df, test.df, classes, k=25)

plot(test.df, col=k)
```

Comment: I think it helps when you add the `classes` vector. So that we can work with content of this object.

Comment: @and I have edited the original post to include my complete code. Again, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you in Hamids class? Ryerson?

Comment: @BDillan just saw your comment after noticing that the question gained some popularity - I was at Ryerson but had Ali Miri for this

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Get the class probability predictions on a grid, and draw a contour line at P=0.5 (or whatever you want the cutoff point to be). This is also the method used in the classic MASS textbook by Venables and Ripley, and in Elements of Statistical Learning by Hastie, Tibshirani and Friedman.

```
# class labels: simple distance from origin
classes <- ifelse(x^2 + y^2 > 60^2, "blue", "orange")
classes.test <- ifelse(x.test^2 + y.test^2 > 60^2, "blue", "orange")

grid <- expand.grid(x=1:100, y=1:100)
classes.grid <- knn(train.df, grid, classes, k=25, prob=TRUE)  # note last argument
prob.grid <- attr(classes.grid, "prob")
prob.grid <- ifelse(classes.grid == "blue", prob.grid, 1 - prob.grid)

# plot the boundary
contour(x=1:100, y=1:100, z=matrix(prob.grid, nrow=100), levels=0.5,
        col="grey", drawlabels=FALSE, lwd=2)
# add points from test dataset
points(test.df, col=classes.test)
```

[image]

See also basically [the same question on CrossValidated.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21572/how-to-plot-decision-boundary-of-a-k-nearest-neighbor-classifier-from-elements-o)