# How to draw an $\alpha$ confidence areas on a 2D-plot?

Tags: r, plot, contour, confidence-interval

There are a lot of answers regarding to [plotting confidence intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069629/plotting-confidence-intervals).

I'm reading the paper by [Lourme A. et al (2016)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.econmod.2016.12.014) and I'd like to draw the 90% confidence boundary and the 10% exceptional points like in the Fig. 2 from the paper: [image].

I can't use LaTeX and insert the picture with the definition of confidence areas:
[image]

```
library("MASS")
library(copula)
set.seed(612)

n <- 1000 # length of sample
d <- 2    # dimension

# random vector with uniform margins on (0,1)
u1 <- runif(n, min = 0, max = 1)
u2 <- runif(n, min = 0, max = 1)

u = matrix(c(u1, u2), ncol=d)

Rg  <- cor(u)   # d-by-d correlation matrix
Rg1 <- ginv(Rg) # inv. matrix 

# round(Rg %*% Rg1, 8) # check

# the multivariate c.d.f of u is a Gaussian copula 
# with parameter Rg[1,2]=0.02876654

normal.cop = normalCopula(Rg[1,2], dim=d)
fit.cop    = fitCopula(normal.cop, u, method="itau") #fitting
# Rg.hat     = fit.cop@estimate[1]
# [1] 0.03097071
sim        = rCopula(n, normal.cop) # in (0,1)

# Taking the quantile function of N1(0, 1)

y1 <- qnorm(sim[,1], mean = 0, sd = 1)
y2 <- qnorm(sim[,2], mean = 0, sd = 1)

par(mfrow=c(2,2))

plot(y1, y2, col="red");  abline(v=mean(y1), h=mean(y2))
plot(sim[,1], sim[,2], col="blue")
hist(y1); hist(y2)
```

**Reference**. 
Lourme, A., F. Maurer (2016) Testing the Gaussian and Student's t copulas in a risk management framework. Economic Modelling.

**Question.** Could anyone help me and give the explanation of the variable `v=(v_1,...,v_d)` and `G(v_1),..., G(v_d)` in the equation?

I think `v` is the non-random matrix, the dimensions should be $k^2$ (grid points) by `d=2` (dimensions). For example,

```
axis_x <- seq(0, 1, 0.1) # 11 grid points
axis_y <- seq(0, 1, 0.1) # 11 grid points
v <- expand.grid(axis_x, axis_y)
plot(v,  type = "p")
```

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23437000/how-to-plot-a-contour-line-showing-where-95-of-values-fall-within-in-r-and-in)?

Comment: @alistaire, thanks for the link, the proposed code gives a solution but it's not appropriate to me because I'd like to plot a "smooth" contour.

Comment: How are you defining this "alpha" confidence boundary from your data points?

Comment: Confidence is always related to an estimate. What are you estimating?

Comment: @Roland, i have tried to add some information about the confidence areas.

Comment: So you *dont* have any code to compute that boundary polygon? That's your first problem? Your second problem being drawing the thing?

Comment: @Spacedman, thanks you for the attention to my question. I have put my current code.

Comment: The questions about the equations are off-topic on SO, I'd say.

Comment: @Axeman, i agree with you. How to migrate to http://math.stackexchange.com/ or http://stats.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @Nick, normally we can migrate, but we can't because of the bounty.

Comment: does https://www.r-bloggers.com/copulas-made-easy/ help ?

Comment: @Drey, thanks but unfortunately not.

Comment: @Nick does my plotting code help you?

Comment: @HongOoi, yes your code very useful. Thanks, is it possible to share 50 reputation between both answers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, your question is about the vector `nu` and correponding `G(nu)`.

`nu` is a simple random vector drawn from *any* distribution that has a domain (0,1). (Here I use uniform distribution). Since you want your samples in 2D one single `nu` can be `nu = runif(2)`. Given the explanations above, `G` is a gaussain pdf with mean 0 and a covariance matrix `Rg`. (Rg has dimensions of 2x2 in 2D).

Now what the paragraph says: if you have a random sample `nu` and you want it to be drawn from `Gamma` given the number of dimensions `d` and confidence level `alpha` then you need to compute the following statistic `(G(nu) %*% Rg^-1) %*% G(nu)` and check that is below the pdf of Chi^2 distribution for `d` and `alpha`.

For example:

```
# This is the copula parameter
Rg <- matrix(c(1,runif(2),1), ncol = 2)
# But we need to compute the inverse for sampling
Rginv <- MASS::ginv(Rg)

sampleResult <- replicate(10000, {
  # we draw our nu from uniform, but others that map to (0,1), e.g. beta, are possible, too
  nu <- runif(2)
  # we compute G(nu) which is a gaussian cdf on the sample
  Gnu <- qnorm(nu, mean = 0, sd = 1)
  # for this we compute the statistic as given in formula
  stat <- (Gnu %*% Rginv) %*% Gnu
  # and return the result
  list(nu = nu, Gnu = Gnu, stat = stat)
})

theSamples <- sapply(sampleResult["nu",], identity)

# this is the critical value of the Chi^2 with alpha = 0.95 and df = number of dimensions
# old and buggy threshold <- pchisq(0.95, df = 2)
# new and awesome - we are looking for the statistic at alpha = .95 quantile
threshold <- qchisq(0.95, df = 2)
# we can accept samples given the threshold (like in equation)
inArea <- sapply(sampleResult["stat",], identity) < threshold

plot(t(theSamples), col = as.integer(inArea)+1)
```

The red points are the points you would keep (I plot all points here).

[image]

As for drawing the decision boundries, I think it is a little bit more complicated, since you need to compute the exact pair of `nu` so that `(Gnu %*% Rginv) %*% Gnu == pchisq(alpha, df = 2)`. It is a linear system that you solve for `Gnu` and then apply inverse to get your `nu` at the decision boundries.

**edit:** Reading the paragraph again, I noticed, the parameter for Gnu does not change, it is simply `Gnu <- qnorm(nu, mean = 0, sd = 1)`.

**edit:** There was a bug: for threshold you need to use the quantile function `qchisq` instead of the distribution function `pchisq` - now corrected in the code above (and updated the figures).

Comment: Note of caution: the code above closely corresponds to the instructions in the paper. However, the results do not completely correspond to that of the paper - the confidence region is different, i.e. `sum(inArea)/length(inArea)` ist not close to `alpha`

Comment: thanks you for the answer. I had voted up. I saw that the value of  sd in the command: Gnu <- qnorm(nu, mean = 0, sd = .25) is the key point. Following to the paper, we should set up sd=1.0 but the confidence region is different. I have tried to calculate mean(sapply(sampleResult["stat",], identity));
sd(sapply(sampleResult["stat",], identity));
hist(sapply(sampleResult["stat",], identity)); but I don't have an idea how to specifide the sd in order to the confidence region will be close to alpha.

Comment: Ah, there was a bug for threshold computation - you need to use `qchisq` instead of `pchisq` - I added explanations above.

Answer (score 1):

This has two parts: first, compute the copula value as a function of X and Y; then, plot the curve giving the boundary where the copula exceeds the threshold.

Computing the value is basically linear algebra which @drey has answered. This is a rewritten version so that the copula is given by a function.

```
cop1 <- function(x)
{
    Gnu <- qnorm(x)
    Gnu %*% Rginv %*% Gnu
}

copula <- function(x)
{
    apply(x, 1, cop1)
}
```

Plotting the boundary curve can be done using the same method as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39822505/drawing-decision-boundaries-in-r/39834037#39834037) (which in turn is the method used by the textbooks Modern Applied Stats with S, and Elements of Stat Learning). Create a grid of values, and use interpolation to find the contour line at the given height.

```
Rg <- matrix(c(1,runif(2),1), ncol = 2)
Rginv <- MASS::ginv(Rg)

# draw the contour line where value == threshold
# define a grid of values first: avoid x and y = 0 and 1, where infinities exist
xlim <- 1e-3
delta <- 1e-3
xseq <- seq(xlim, 1-xlim, by=delta)
grid <- expand.grid(x=xseq, y=xseq)
prob.grid <- copula(grid)
threshold <- qchisq(0.95, df=2)

contour(x=xseq, y=xseq, z=matrix(prob.grid, nrow=length(xseq)), levels=threshold,
        col="grey", drawlabels=FALSE, lwd=2)

# add some points
data <- data.frame(x=runif(1000), y=runif(1000))
points(data, col=ifelse(copula(data) < threshold, "red", "black"))
```

[image]